# Can't Create .NET 5 Console App In Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, .net-5

I need to be able to create .NET 5 Console applications in Visual Studio 2019.

I have the .NET 5 SDK installed.  The Terminal command "dotnet --list-sdks" proves that:

```
5.0.408 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
6.0.300 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

However, I don't see the .NET 5 Console app option when creating a new project:

[image]

It only shows the Console App for .NET Framework.  If I try creating one of those, only the .NET Framework frameworks are listed in the framework dropdown:

[image]

Based on other posts, I've tried enabling the option to "Use previews of the .NET SDK".  I've also tried repairing Visual Studio.  Neither action allows for the option to create .NET 5 Console applications.  I have the following components installed in Visual Studio.  Is there something else I need to install?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in fact, on my VS19 there is no .NET5 either, but on VS22, there I can .NET5 and even .NET6 (see picture)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to Visual Studio 2022 and I can create Console apps there.